# Error when Typesetting with Bibliography in TeXShop

Tags: bibtex, pdftex

I recently switched from Windows 10 to Mac OSX 11.4 and have installed TeXShop 4.66. I'm looking to typeset a file, called "paper8.tex", that typesets with no issues on my Windows machine using pdfLaTeX+makeIndex+BibTeX. However, when I try to compile using pdflatexmk on my Mac OSX 11.4 I run into the following error

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2021)
The top-level auxiliary file: paper8.aux
The style file: te.bst
Database file #1: library.bib
Warning--empty note in Gu2018
Warning--missing publisher in kahnemanNoise
"" can't start a style-file command---line 1518 of file te.bst
 : 
 : 
(Error may have been on previous line)
(There was 1 error message)
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  bibtex paper8: Bibtex errors: See file 'paper8.blg'
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
```

See here https://www.dropbox.com/s/45999m4wr45jb80/te.bst?dl=0 for the `te.bst` that appears to be causing the issue. Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a minimal working example (including, e.g., a tex file and a bib) for your question.

Comment: Line 1518 appears to be the last in your .bst file. I opened it in emacs and found some sort of control character there. I suspect you just need to delete this.

Comment: Hi @IanThompson - thanks the response. I opened ``te.bst`` and found an extra empty line at Line 1518. Thanks for the solution and sorry for the dumb question -- I didn't realize an empty line would trigger an error!

Comment: There was a character on line 1518, but it probably wouldn't show up in all editors. Lots of them try to be 'helpful' by hiding these. This sort of problem can be really annoying - it's not a 'dumb question' at all.

Answer (score 1):

Line 1518 is the final line of the .bst file. There is a strange character on this line, which will show up differently in different editors.

[image: notepad]

[image: emacs]

The presence of this character upsets bibtex. Simply deleting line 1518 will resolve the problem.

Comment: Thanks @IanThompson!